# Tiny Flies eating my freshly germinated seed stems

Tags: trees

I am trying to grow some trees, however after germination of the seeds, I place them in a "growth media" which has "bonemeal" included in it, and this seems to be what is attracting the flies. They seem to be eating the small stems and killing off my tree - Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you might have mice.  Could that be a possibility?  Your growth medium, was it sterilized potting soil?  Flies don't eat plants.  Mice do.  Put domes over your starts?  Is this in a grow room with artificial lights?

Comment: @stormy, the critters that "non-expert" people might call "flies" aren't necessarily what a biologist would classify as flies (i.e. *Diptera* species). There are certainly insects which "look like flies" (and may even be *able* to fly!) that eat leaves, suck sap, etc.

Comment: A picture would help!

Comment: Almost sounds like a combination of fungus gnats and damping off. A picture is really essential.

Comment: Need a picture for sure.  When I've forgotten to put a dome on my seedlings and weight it down, my seedlings always got eaten by mice.  Need a lot more information and a picture is worth a 1000?    I was just giving a bit of grist to consider while we wait for a picture.  Alpherzero I am on the same page. Jurp's fungus gnats are most likely for the flies.  Do we have a short questionnaire for New contributors yet?  Most questions could actually be answered faster, more concisely (by moi ) having the most important information up front and definitely would help the OP form their question.